# How to prove this inequality

Tags: integration

To  prove  $${1\over k^p}\lt \int_{k-1}^k {1\over x^p} dx$$
where $p\gt 1$.

My take **:**

$$L=\int_{k-1}^k {1\over x^p}dx\\={1\over {p-1}}\left({1\over{(k-1)^{p-1}}}-{1\over {k^{p-1}}}\right)\\={1\over {p-1}} \left({k^{p-1}-(k-1)^{p-1}}\over {(k(k-1))^{p-1}}\right)$$
 If the above inequality  is  to hold  then what must hold is that $$(p-1)\lt {k\over{(k-1)^{p-1}}}\cdot \left[k^{p-1}-(k-1)^{p-1} \right]\\ ={k\over{(k-1)^{p-1}}}\cdot \left[\{1-(k-1)\}^{p-1}-(k-1)^{p-1} \right]$$

What  next $?$

Answer (score 4):

It's much easier.
Just note that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$ is strictly decreasing over $\mathbb{R}^+$.
Hence $f(x) > f(k)=\frac{1}{k^p}$ for all $x < k$.
In particular,
$$\int_{k-1}^k \frac{1}{x^p} dx=\int_{k-1}^k f(x) dx >  \int_{k-1}^k f(k) dx=f(k)=\frac{1}{k^p}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $k>1$, this can be done much more simply:

Since $f(x)=1/x^p$ is strictly decreasing
$$f(x)>1/k^p$$
for all $0<x<k$.

So,
$$\int_{k-1}^k\frac 1{x^p}\,dx>\int_{k-1}^k\frac 1{k^p}\,dx=\frac1{k^p}\int_{k-1}^kdx=\frac1{k^p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

By a well-known result there exists $k-1<c<k$ such that $(k-(k-1)){1\over{c^p}}$ is the integrale

Comment: Please name this result or give a reference. I think you are referring to the mean-value theorem perhaps?

Comment: Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^bf(t)dt = (b-a)f(c)$